# Controlling the space between caption and listing

Tags: listings

I have a listing environment, but the space between caption and listing is too large. I could use \vspace to control it, but in this case, I should add the command to all of my listings. Is there a way to change them?

[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfP6u.png)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{listings}

\colorlet{punct}{red!60!black} 
\definecolor{background}{HTML}{EEEEEE}
\definecolor{delim}{RGB}{20,105,176}
\definecolor{ogreen}{rgb}{0.0, 0.5, 0.0}
\colorlet{numb}{magenta!60!black} 

\DeclareCaptionType{codetype}[Listing][List of mytype]
\newenvironment{code}{}{}

\lstset{ %
    basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily,
    frame=L,
    xleftmargin=\parindent,
}

\lstdefinelanguage{hello}{
        emph={grammar, filter, def, class, end, typedef, type, constraint, sentence},
        emphstyle=\textbf,
        escapechar=\,
        basicstyle=\ttfamily\scriptsize,
        numbers=left, % <---- 
        numberstyle=\ttfamily\scriptsize,
        stepnumber=1,
        numbersep=3pt,
        showstringspaces=false,
        breaklines=true,
        frame=lines,
        framerule=1pt,
        rulesep=1pt,
        framexleftmargin=2em,
        literate=
         *{0}{{{\color{numb}0}}}{1}
            {1}{{{\color{numb}1}}}{1}
            {2}{{{\color{numb}2}}}{1}
            {3}{{{\color{numb}3}}}{1}
            {4}{{{\color{numb}4}}}{1}
            {5}{{{\color{numb}5}}}{1}
            {6}{{{\color{numb}6}}}{1}
            {7}{{{\color{numb}7}}}{1}
            {8}{{{\color{numb}8}}}{1}
            {9}{{{\color{numb}9}}}{1}
            {:}{{{\color{punct}{:}}}}{1}
            {,}{{{\color{punct}{,}}}}{1}
            {\{}{{{\color{delim}{\{}}}}{1}
            {\}}{{{\color{delim}{\}}}}}{1}
            {[}{{{\color{delim}{[}}}}{1}
            {]}{{{\color{delim}{]}}}}{1},
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htpb]
    \begin{lstlisting}[language=hello,firstnumber=1]
        function bool priceMatch(produceName, price) = {
             return 
             ( produceName == "apple" &&  0 <= price <= 1000 )
        }
    \end{lstlisting}
    \captionof{codetype}{Type definitions}
    \label{code:function}
    \end{figure}

    \begin{figure}[htpb]
    \begin{lstlisting}[language=hello,firstnumber=1]
        function bool priceMatch(produceName, price) = {
             return 
             ( produceName == "apple" &&  0 <= price <= 1000 )
        }
    \end{lstlisting}
    \vspace{-0.5cm}
    \captionof{codetype}{Type definitions}

    \label{code:function}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

### ADDED

With this change, the gap issue is solved, but the \ref does not work; it is left as `??`.

```
    \begin{lstlisting}[language=hello,firstnumber=1, 
        abovecaptionskip=0pt, caption={Type definitions}, captionpos=b]
```

[image]

Comment: if you want to control the space between the listing and the caption, you need to put `\vspace` between the listing and caption.

Comment: @David Carlisle: Thanks, I revised question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was wondering why you didn't use the caption's key of lstlistings with captionpos and abovecaptionskip or belowcaptionskip?

I suggest the following solution with respect to above keys.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{listings}

\colorlet{punct}{red!60!black} 
\definecolor{background}{HTML}{EEEEEE}
\definecolor{delim}{RGB}{20,105,176}
\definecolor{ogreen}{rgb}{0.0, 0.5, 0.0}
\colorlet{numb}{magenta!60!black} 

\DeclareCaptionType{codetype}[Listing][List of mytype]
\newenvironment{code}{}{}

\lstset{ %
    basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily,
    frame=L,
    xleftmargin=\parindent,
}

\lstdefinelanguage{hello}{
        emph={grammar, filter, def, class, end, typedef, type, constraint, sentence},
        emphstyle=\textbf,
        escapechar=\,
        basicstyle=\ttfamily\scriptsize,
        numbers=left, % <---- 
        numberstyle=\ttfamily\scriptsize,
        stepnumber=1,
        numbersep=3pt,
        showstringspaces=false,
        breaklines=true,
        frame=lines,
        framerule=1pt,
        rulesep=1pt,
        framexleftmargin=2em,
        literate=
         *{0}{{{\color{numb}0}}}{1}
            {1}{{{\color{numb}1}}}{1}
            {2}{{{\color{numb}2}}}{1}
            {3}{{{\color{numb}3}}}{1}
            {4}{{{\color{numb}4}}}{1}
            {5}{{{\color{numb}5}}}{1}
            {6}{{{\color{numb}6}}}{1}
            {7}{{{\color{numb}7}}}{1}
            {8}{{{\color{numb}8}}}{1}
            {9}{{{\color{numb}9}}}{1}
            {:}{{{\color{punct}{:}}}}{1}
            {,}{{{\color{punct}{,}}}}{1}
            {\{}{{{\color{delim}{\{}}}}{1}
            {\}}{{{\color{delim}{\}}}}}{1}
            {[}{{{\color{delim}{[}}}}{1}
            {]}{{{\color{delim}{]}}}}{1},
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htpb]
    \begin{lstlisting}[language=hello,firstnumber=1]
        function bool priceMatch(produceName, price) = {
             return 
             ( produceName == "apple" &&  0 <= price <= 1000 )
        }
    \end{lstlisting}
    \captionof{lstlisting}{Type definitions}
    \label{code:function}
    \end{figure}

    \begin{figure}[htpb]
    \begin{lstlisting}[language=hello,firstnumber=1, 
        abovecaptionskip=0pt, caption={Type definitions}, captionpos=b, label={code:test}]
        function bool priceMatch(produceName, price) = {
             return 
             ( produceName == "apple" &&  0 <= price <= 1000 )
        }
    \end{lstlisting}
%    \captionof{codetype}{Type definitions}
%    \vspace{-1cm}
    \label{code:function}
    \end{figure}

This is a reference to a code \ref{code:test}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The ref doesn't work with this setup. I revised the question.

Comment: use label key of lstlisting and the ref works with it.

Comment: @prosseek I revised the solution, see that.